# Parse a config file in PHP (key value)

Tags: php

I have a config file which structure looks like this:

```
#comment1
key1 value1

#comment2
key-key2 value2

#comment3
key3 value3 value4
```

I have been trying to parse this in PHP with the following code:

```php
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
$config = [];

foreach ($lines as $l) {
    preg_match("/^(?P<key>\w+)\s+(?P<value>.*)/", $l, $matches);

    if (isset($matches['key'])) {
        $config[$matches['key']] = $matches['value'];
    }
}
```

However I am not able to get the regex right, the above regex is only functioning for the line with #comment1, it does not parse key-key2 properly and #comment3 key-value has 2 values which should just be 1 string inside the array.

Output I wish to have:

```
[
   'key1' => 'value1',
   'key-key2' => 'value2',
   'key3' => 'value3 value4'
]
```

Anyone able to help me with the regex?

Comment: How do you read the file? Big blob or line by line

Comment: Line by line (I am exploding on PHP_EOL (newline) in the string content)

Comment: So `$lines` is in fact just a single line ?

Comment: $lines is the array, and I foreach through it, $l is the line itself inside the foreach.

Comment: You might want to just explode the line on space and check that count = 2.

Comment: If it were me I'd change the config file to JSON.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This is not possible, the file I demonstrated (with #comment1 etc) is how I receive it, and I have to parse that. I would love to get it in JSON but simply not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be simple enough not to have to use regex as you can check for `#` at the start of the line easily enough and then use `explode()` with a space and limit of 2 parts to extract the key and data...

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
$config = [];

foreach ($lines as $l) {
    if ( !empty($l) && $l[0] != '#' ) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(" ", $l, 2);
        $config[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($config);
```

Comment: Great solution actually, never thought of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing code; just explode each line on space limiting to 2 elements and check that you get 2 elements:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

foreach ($lines as $l) {
    if(count($parts = explode(' ' , $l, 2)) == 2) {
        $config[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];   
    }
}
```

Comment: This has problems when the comment has a space in it.